# Do we have $u^2 \leq u$ when $\|u \| \leq 1$ in a $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $u$ be a positive element in a $C^*$-algebra $A$ with $\|u \|\le 1$. Then is it true that $u^2 \leq u$?

**Attempt**: This is true in the commutative $C^*$-subalgebra $C^*(u)$, since by the Gelfand-Naimark theorem, $C^*(u) \cong C_0(X)$ where $X$ is some locally compact Hausdorff space. Thus, this also holds in $A$ since positivity does not depend on the ambenient $C^*$-subalgebra.

Is this correct?

Comment: What if $A=\mathbb C$, $u=-1$?

Comment: @Aweygan Fair point, luckily where I need it $u$ is also positive.

Comment: I edited the post accordingly. Is it correct then?

Comment: Yes, it's now correct.  I'll answer shortly

Comment: Thanks for the verification! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $u$ positive and $\|u\|\leq1$, you get $0\leq u\leq 1$. Also, being positive, $u$ has a (unique) positive square root.

Then
$$
u-u^2=u^{1/2}(1-u)u^{1/2}\geq0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume $A$ is unital.  Then $C^*(u,1)\cong C(\sigma(u)$, the continuous functions on the spectrum of $u$, and this isomorphism takes $u$ to the inclusion function, $\sigma(u)\ni\lambda\mapsto\lambda\in\mathbb C$. The conditions that $u$ is positive and $\|u\|\leq1$ then imply that $0\leq \lambda\leq 1$ for all $\lambda\in\sigma$, and for such $\lambda$, $\lambda^2\leq\lambda$.  Using the above isomorphism, this yields that $u^2\leq u$.